# How can I change the default GUID connection string in a LightSwitch web.config file using Wix?

Tags: wix, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a LightSwitch HTMLClient application that must use Wix as the deployment solution.

The Wix project is setup such that an external transform file will modify the default connection string used in the web.config file:

```
<util:XmlFile Id="SetConnectionString"
    File="[#web.config]"
    Action="setValue"
    ElementPath="configuration/connectionStrings/add[\[]@name = 'Example_App_DatabaseData'[\]]"
    Name="connectionString"
    Value="[CONFIG_CONNECTIONSTRING]" />
```

Previously I had in my web.config file three connection strings:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="_IntrinsicData" connectionString="Data Source=|SqlExpressInstanceName|;AttachDbFilename=|ApplicationDatabasePath|;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
  <add name="Example_App_DatabaseData" connectionString="Data Source=db_server\sql01;Initial Catalog=Example.App.Database;Integrated Security=True" />
  <add name="5f204b97-b94a-4154-b050-2f3f6d863ea4" connectionString="Data Source=db_server\sql01;Initial Catalog=Example.App.Database;Integrated Security=True" />
</connectionStrings>
```

But I've recently discovered that the default LightSwitch GUID connectionString turns into a duplicated 'Example_App_DatabaseData' connectionString when built so I was ending up with a duplicated entry in the web.config file.

The problem is that if I remove the 'Example_App_DatabaseData' connectionString then when I attempt to apply my transform file, and thus set the value the connectionsString doesn't actually exist.

Is there some way of setting the default GUID connectionString through Wix without it needing a hardcoded connectionString name? Or really just to make the final web.config look like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="_IntrinsicData" connectionString="Data Source=|SqlExpressInstanceName|;AttachDbFilename=|ApplicationDatabasePath|;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
  <add name="Example_App_DatabaseData" connectionString="Data Source=db_server\sql01;Initial Catalog=Example.App.Database;Integrated Security=True" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Thanks in advance!